# preserve url when using AWS Route53 alias record set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-route53

I have a cloudfront in front of my s3 website written in angular and the domain is mydomain.io

I have configured an alias record set in route53: seconddomain.io that target the first cloudfront.

If I use the alias domain “seconddomain.io” i can navigate in the app and the url in the navigation is correct (seconddomain.io/ramdomPath).
But If I tried to refresh the browser that contain a path (seconddmain.io/user/me) it switched back to (mydomain.io/user/me).
It also switched back to mydomain.io/random if I tried to access seconddomain.io/random directly

the routing rules for mydomain.io s3 bucket is the following:

```html
<RoutingRules>
    <RoutingRule>
        <Condition>
            <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
        </Condition>
        <Redirect>
            <Protocol>https</Protocol>
            <HostName>mydomain.io</HostName>
            <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>#!/</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

I suspect the hostname tag to be the cause of the problem, but I am not sure.

**edit**:I don't know if my approach is correct but what I am trying to achieve is that I want to give a different domain for each company that are using the same application

Comment: Yes, that is likely the issue, but what is the purpose of having 2 different domains?

Comment: I don't know if my approach is correct but what I am trying to achieve is that I want to give a different domain for each company that are using the same application.